# R Filtering results using text input from a select box or selectInput

Tags: r, filter, rstudio, shiny

I am learning/playing/modifying Winston's great movie explorer in the shiny gallery.

Here is his server.ui code. https://github.com/wch/movies/blob/master/server.R

In his example, he used simple numeric slider range filtering for numeric movie data.

That was followed with text filtering, and this is where I run into error.

He used text input, (textInput http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widgets-gallery.html)

I run into error attempting to filter (possibly multiple) text values from a list with a select box, (selectInput http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widgets-gallery.html).

```
# Optional: filter by director
if (!is.null(input$director) && input$director != "") {
director <- paste0("%", input$director, "%")
m <- m %>% filter(Director %like% director)
}
```

Attempting to implement his director filter code identically, other than supplying "director" via a select box (rather than textInput), RStudio responds with...

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, dots(...), environment()) : 
could not find function "%like%"
```

After much digging I believe that though it wasn't mentioned, I also may need the library(data.table) installed.

After installing and loading data.table, the error now changes to

```
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in fdata[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I believe the warnings (not errors) refer to ggvis,

The fdata error is occurs on line 61 of his server.r code

m <- as.data.frame(m)

And this is where I find myself completely at a loss as for how to proceed.

The solution would either include an arguably superior method of filtering, or help me put the wheels back on this example's wagon.

Thank you for your time.

Oh my goodness! 
I am stunned by the rapid responses, they were responding before the full question was clearly typed.
I am importing a CSV rather than using the SQL tie in.
All 4 librarys are loaded.

Comment: Did you load all the four libraries he mentioned at the beginning?

Comment: Did you try changing anything in the code? There is a reference to `%like%` in `dplyr` but it only seems to work in the context of `translate_sql` (ie `translate_sql(first %like% "Had*")`). Are you no longer using a SQL back end? There is no stand-alone operator called `%like%` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MrFlick, `%like%` looks awfully like `SQL` syntax I'd assumed it has to be in the last two packages, but was too lazy to check

Comment: The only other package I know of that has the function `%like%` is `data.table` - but I'm curious to know how the author of that `server.R` file was able to get away with not using that package. I did check all of the packages loaded in that file and did not find `%like%`.

Comment: So why on earth this question down-voted so hard lol

Comment: If I had to guess, i'd say the references to RSQLite had been removed during modification. And since the DB was the thing that performed the LIKE and there is no R equivalent, that's why the error is appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought, this does seem to be specific to using `RSQLite`. Here's an example

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

#sample data    
dd<-data.frame(name=letters[1:5], age=21:25)

dd %>% filter(age==25)
#   name age
# 1    e  25

dd %>% filter(name %like% a)
# Error in filter_impl(.data, dots(...), environment()) : 
#   could not find function "%like%"
```

But now let's create a test sqlite database.

```
#sample sqlite database
sqlite    <- dbDriver("SQLite")
exampledb <- dbConnect(sqlite,"hello.db")
dbWriteTable(exampledb, "people", dd)
sqliteCloseConnection(exampledb)
sqliteCloseDriver(sqlite)
```

and now we will use `dplyr` to filter again

```
db <- src_sqlite("hello.db", create=F)
nm <- tbl(db, "people")

nm %>% filter(age==25)
#   row_names name age
# 1         5    e  25

nm %>% filter(name %like% a)
#   row_names name age
# 1         1    a  21
```

And it works. Do `%like%` isn't a proper R infix operator. It's simply a command that gets escaped and translated when using a SQL connection to the appropriate SQL command.